# CI/CD pipeline on AWS cloud for pyspark EMR application

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy, aws-codecommit

I need to create CI/CD pipeline in AWS cloud for a pyspark application , finally this py-spark is to be invoked through a airflow DAG.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on this either, but you can follow this guide:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/implement-continuous-integration-and-delivery-of-apache-spark-applications-using-aws/

The idea is to automate job testing in Spark local mode, then run a live job with infrastructure created on the fly and finally deploy the job to production if all the previous steps succeed. I would keep my production jobs automated in Airflow and run this CI/CD pipeline on development branches (these ones without deploying to production, of course) as well as on PR on the main branch. That way your production jobs will always be functioning correctly and only incorporate new functionality/changes after they are fully tested on development branches.

Comment: Also I'd like to figure out how to implement this on Gitlab and using Terraform since these are more common DevOps tools than the AWS ones. Please let me know if you figured out an alternative.